# Howto prompt for password when running tibco EMS script

Tags: tibco, ems

It is possible to run an ems script using

```
tibemsadmin -server tcp://localhost:7222 -user <username> -password <password> -script <file>
```

however, this of course makes your password visible in ps, top, etc, and also in any shell history. Is it possible to run a tibco script and be prompted for the password? Just omiting the -password flag results in "invalid user or password" user.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `tibemsadmin` with just the script argument, you can then put the `connect` command in your script, which can contain the username and password. If a password is not specified for the `connect` command, then the user will be prompted to enter a password.

Comment: Works well, except if I don't provide a password, no prompt is given, just an error, "Error in line 1: invalid syntax or command failed"

Comment: Looks like you've found a defect. The Command Listing page in the [EMS docs](http://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.0.1_january_2011/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) states "If a user name or password are not provided, the user is prompted to enter a user name and password, or only the password, if the user name was already specified in the command." I'd raise a support ticket with TIBCO, though they may simply indicate that it's a documentation defect.

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge it is not possible to achieve the behaviour you want just using tibemsadmin.
However you have (at least) two alternatives to solve your issue:

- option 1) use the EMS APIs and write a program to perform what you need to do
- option 2) use third party tools (e.g. [EMS Butler](http://www.kavamala.com/emsbutler.php)) that support password encryption and use a separate credentials file, so the password is not shown

Hope this helps.

Daniele